# Warning:com.qoppa.viewer.b.h: can't find referenced class android.graphics.PixelXorXfermode

Tags: android, pdf

I am getting this warning  while i am trying to generate signed APK file.
In my project i used **qoppa** library to create pdf files. can any one please help me to fix this. Should i need to write anything in my **proguard** file to fix this?

Comment: Since you tagged this question as an iText question, I  would suggest that you use iText. (If you want to continue using Qoppa, why don't you ask Qoppa for support?)

Comment: iText tag deleted. There appears to be no qoppa tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to the fact that the class PixelXorXfermode was removed in Android API Level 24:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes/pkg_android.graphics.html

To resolve the issue, download the latest version of qPDF Toolkit 5.6 from Qoppa's website in which this class is no longer used.